# method dependency in testng.xml

Tags: testng

I am trying to add method dependency in testng.xml, but this does not seem to work. could someone suggest, what am i missing here.

```html
<suite name="Test Suite for End To End">
 <test name="AUT_E2E_01">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
  <classes>
   <class name="com.myunit.regressiontests">
    <methods>
     <include name="AutTC03" />
     <include name="AutTC11" dependsOnMethods="AutTC03" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `dependsOnMethods` is not allowed there (see [TestNG DTD](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php)).

Here are some excerpts from [TestNG Documentation - 5.7 - Dependencies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) (*links added for convenience*):

> TestNG allows you to specify dependencies either with annotations or in XML.
>
> [**5.7.1 - Dependencies with annotations**](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations)
>
> You can use the attributes [`dependsOnMethods`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#dependsOnMethods()) or [`dependsOnGroups`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#dependsOnGroups()), found on the [`@Test`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html) annotation.
>
> [**5.7.2 - Dependencies in XML**](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml)
>
> Alternatively, you can specify your group dependencies in the [`testng.xml`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) file.

i.e. You can define "group" dependencies in both Java and in XML but you can only define "method" dependencies in Java (using the [`@Test`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html) annotation).

However, even though you cannot define "method" dependencies in XML you can place your methods in groups to use instead.

e.g. The following assumes that you have placed `AutTC03` and `AutTC11` into [test groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) named `AutTC03-Group` and `AutTC11-Group` respectively:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test Suite for End To End">
    <test name="AUT_E2E_01">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.myunit.regressiontests">
                <methods>
                    <include name="AutTC03" />
                    <include name="AutTC11" dependsOnMethods="AutTC03" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
        <groups>
            <dependencies>
                <group name="AutTC11-Group" depends-on="AutTC03-Group" />
            </dependencies>
        </groups>
    </test>
</suite>
```